# What is the 'to=' positional argument in ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

In my project (I am learning Django, so it's a very basic one) I am trying to implement a relationship such as 'an order can have multiple meal items'. So after checking the documentation, I realised that this can be rather implemented as 'a meal item can be in one ore more orders' through the use of the `ForeingKey` field class.

On the Django documentation page for [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/) it is said:

> 'Requires two positional arguments: the class to which the model is
>   related and the on_delete option.'

But just passing these two arguments and trying to make the migrations  throws an error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'to' and 'on_delete'
```

Now, my `Meal` class in models.py looks like so:

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('meals:detail', kwargs={'id': self.id})
```

I think the problem is due to the fact that the two classes (Order and Meal) are implemented as two different apps (not even sure if that's the way to organise things for reuse).

So back to the documentation, when I look to the arguments for ForeignKey it doesn't say anything about the `to=` positional argument. I noticed, though, that there are `to_field`, and `limit_choices_to`.

Is it one of them that is asking for? Also, why it's still asking for `on_delate` when I am actually passing a value for it? And finally where I can find documentation for this `to=` positional argument?

Thanks

This is how I create an object of the `Meal` class:

```
class MealCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = MealCreateForm
    template_name = 'meals/meal_create.html'
    queryset = Meal.objects.all()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Note that this view is inside the meals pakage, which is a different app from orders.

And this is how I create an object of the Order class:

```
class OrderCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = OrderCreateForm
    template_name = 'orders/order_create.html'
    queryset = Order.objects.all()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: how are you creating the object of this class? where/when is the error message being thrown? Note that in the portion you pasted from the docs: it says: **the class to which the model is related**

Comment: I create the object through a create view, and the error is thrown when running the python manage.py makemigration command. I thought the class to which the model is related to is Order.

Comment: Check your classes positions. Foreign key can be done if only foreign object class is under main class. So, your order class have to be on top of meal class.

Comment: Ok, so basically both classes have to be in the same package right? (Which makes sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('meals:detail', kwargs={'id': self.id}
```

if your Order class is not in the same app import it, or if it is in same app either place it on top of Meal class or put put Order in quotes ("Order")

Comment: I guess this is the solution, to move both classes in the same package. Thanks